# Eloquent Laravel 5 won't accept parameter from post

Tags: php, laravel-5, eloquent

I'm pretty new working with laravel 5 and Eloquent.

so i want to pass post variable and using it as parameter in my query

```
public function getDepartmentList(Request $request){
    $divisi_id = $request->input('divisi_id');
    $departmentList = departemen::all()->where('divisi_id', $divisi_id);
```

here is my problem. $divisi_id containing data from post. but when I pass it in eloquent, $divisi_id is losing it's value, so the query return empty. but when i change the value from post to pre defined value `$divisi_id = 1`, the query returned with some rows. so, I think the problem is the post.

is there any way to pass post data to the Eluqoent?

Comment: Can you share the result of `var_dump($_POST);` right inside that method.

Comment: here the result

array(1) { ["divisi_id"]=> string(1) "1" } 

well, I was able to print the post or print the variable that i used that contain the post. but strangely, eloquent won't accept it. but when I try to add the post with +0, eloquent accept the parameter.

Comment: in the above mentioned code try dd($divisi_id); on line number 3 and see if you have value in $divisi_id

Comment: i got the value from `$divisi_id`. the problem only lies when i pass it to the eloquent. when i use standard query like `DB::select('select * from departemen where divisi_id = '.$divisi_id.';')` everything goes fine

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**Please change:**

```
DB::select('select * from departemen where divisi_id = '.$divisi_id.';')
```

To

```
DB::select('select * from departemen where divisi_id = $divisi_id)
```

For eloquent:

```
$departmentList = departemen::where('divisi_id', $divisi_id)->get();
```

Comment: like i said. standard query like `DB::select` working fine. the problem lies when i use Eloquent

Comment: $departmentList = departemen::where('divisi_id', $divisi_id)->get();

without **all**

Comment: thank you very much. it saved me. i don't know why in my netbeans won't show suggestion `departemen::where` instead `departemen::all()->where`. i thought it was wrong.